# How to defer below google map and facebook javascripts and also jquery.js without harming slider revolution in wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, plugins, deferred

I am having some problem to defer parsing javascripts. when i defer jquery.js my slider revolution is not working on front end. but when i logged in admin dashboard the it works fine. and also i not able to defer external javascript files like google map and facebook..

here is my code to defer javascripts-

```
if (!(is_admin() )) {
    function defer_parsing_of_js ( $url ) {
        if ( FALSE === strpos( $url, '.js' ) ) return $url;
        if ( strpos( $url, 'jquery.js' ) ) return $url;
        // return "$url' defer ";
        return "$url' defer onload='";
    }
    add_filter( 'clean_url', 'defer_parsing_of_js', 11, 1 );
}
```

Comment: send me your website url

Comment: https://marchesi.com.au/ this is my website url..

Answer (score 0):

```
function defer_parsing_of_js ( $url ) 
{
    if( !is_admin() )
    {
        if ( FALSE === strpos( $url, '.js' ) ) return $url;
        if ( strpos( $url, 'jquery.js' ) ) return $url;
        return "$url' defer ";
    }
    return $url;
}
add_filter( 'clean_url', 'defer_parsing_of_js', 11, 1 );
```

**can you try this code**

Comment: i know but i want decrease load time below 5 second or more. you can check my website performance in GT matrix

Comment: @Dev5 i suggest you use any cache plugin and use cdn server for website optimization

Comment: i used many cached plugin but because of these plugin several services not working like grid gallery.. but i haven't used cdn optimisation yet so can you please suggest me how can i do this..

Comment: @Dev5 wprocket cache plugin is best plugin can you try eprocket wordpress plugin

Comment: @Dev5 i have many website optimization with stackpath cdn and w3rocket wordpress plugin

Comment: is this a paid plugin.. pls send me the link when i can download this plugin.

Comment: @Dev5 This is paid plugin